# Why won't this script run?

Tags: image, powershell

```
# Set the path to the AOMEI Backupper Technician executable
$abtExecutable = "C:\Program Files (x86)\AOMEI Backupper Technician\Backupper.exe"

# Set the destination for the system image backup
$backupDestination = "C:\Backups\System Image"

# Set the password for the backup
$password = "12121212121212121212"

# Set the compression level to 'high'
$compression = "high"

# Check if there is already a system image backup from 30 days ago
$thirtyDaysAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$oldBackup = Get-ChildItem $backupDestination | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $thirtyDaysAgo }

# If there is an old backup, delete it
if ($oldBackup) {
  Remove-Item -Path $oldBackup.FullName -Force
}

# Create the full system image backup
    & $abtExecutable backup system -d $backupDestination -p $password -c $compression
```

Whenever I try to run this in Powershell, the most it does is it launches the AOMEI backupper exe. But it doesn't do any of the other steps.

I expected it to work. Whenever I try to run this in Powershell, the most it does is it launches the AOMEI backupper exe. But it doesn't do any of the other steps.

Comment: If you mean running this from the console. See the examples that powershell.exe shows you. ```powershell /?```. The last two in that list should help you out. If you are running from a script, why call the console at all, just use ```Start-Process``` in your script with the argument list to pass parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment,

```
powershell /?

EXAMPLES
    ...
    PowerShell -Command {Get-EventLog -LogName security}
    PowerShell -Command "& {Get-EventLog -LogName security}"
```

[PowerShell- Running Executables - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

doing your console stuff in a script via `Start-Process`.

```
$ConsoleCommand = 'Some Console Command'

$startProcessSplat = @{
    FilePath     = 'powershell'
    ArgumentList = '-NoExit', 'NoProfile', '-Command  &{ $ConsoleCommand }'
    Wait         = $true
}
Start-Process @startProcessSplat
```

Or just call directly in your script without calling the powershell console at all, since your `$abtExecutable` is a stand-alone executable and really calls `cmd.exe` to run, which `Start-Process` will do by default.